# How to enter string in python two-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays

Why do I get only the first character in the result?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RX3s5.png)

```
label = np.empty([17,2],dtype=str)
label[1][1]="asd"
label[2][1]="asd"
print(label)
```

I don't know if np.empty can input a string

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Post the code as formatted text

Comment: Please provide your actual code instead of img.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use dtype='object' instead of 'str'

test = np.empty((2,2), dtype='object')

test[0,0] = "ashok"

print(test)

Explanation : actually string is object which hold the character array values. so by default indexing in string location the first char not whole string.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDhrv.png)